# SVN pegged externals unxpected behavior

Tags: svn, svn-externals

We are using svn:externals with pegged revisions to re-use common components.
We've noticed some unexpected behavior which I suspect may be a bug.
Let's assume we have a folder A which has an svn:externals property which points to folder B at revision 180.
When I update folder A in my working copy I indeed get folder A and folder B at revision 180.
However, when I update folder B only (select B in Windows Explorer and click TortoiseSvn Update) I get it's HEAD revision and not 180.

Is this the expected behavior?

We're using TortoiseSvn 1.8.3 and server version 1.7.

Thank You,
Shay

Comment: I don't know if it's intended behavior but I can understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the expected behavior?

Yes, "external" folder in WC is nested independent WC of subtree in another repository, which have no information about relation with wrapper-repo. Thus - ordinary `svn up` work in usual way: update WC to HEAD